# Scroll to the bottom of a web page on a element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

How do you scroll on a scrolling element in Python Selenium? (not the page itself but some element where you can scroll)

For example, go here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724150/how-can-i-create-a-list-of-pictures-and-add-text-only-on-one-of-them-using-pillo)

Then hit enter a lot of times in the "answer" text box. You can see that it creates a scroll bar on the text box only. How do I scroll through that in Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the locator for that scroll bar using inspect element and then do scrolling on that

```
document.querySelector('textarea#wmd-input').scrollBy(0,500)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium isnt like pyautogui where you need coordinates of drag and drop functions, you just need to find the element you want to interact with and use that - check out the docs for more info:
[Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)